# Docker Container Connect to MSSQL: Worked Yesterday

Tags: docker, tcp, docker-for-windows

I am new to docker and getting very confused. Yesterday, I set up a MSSQL docker image and it is running. Some output of `docker ps -a`:

```
IMAGE: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server CREATED: 25 hours ago 
STATUS: Up 25 hours  PORTS: 0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp
```

I am trying to connect remotely to run a script. Yesterday I was able to

```
sqlcmd -S <myIP>,1433 -U SA -P "<myPassword>" -i ./sql-scripts/all.sql -o "out.txt"
```

but today when I run the same exact command I get

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

Does anyone know what could change between today and yesterday to make this happen? Using windows 10 enterprise, docker for windows, TSQL. I also tried https://canyouseeme.org/ and confirmed that port 1433 is not open on my IP.

EDIT: I should probably note I'm still able to access `sqlcmd` repl inside the container with `docker exec -it mySecondServer "bash"` and then `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA` inside.

EDIT 2: Today the same error happened and when I tried to restart my docker container (still not the solution I want) I got

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mySecondServer (9d...): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:1433:tcp:172.17.0.2:1433: input/output error
Error: failed to start containers: 85...
```

Comment: Yesterday it worked. Today it does not. Microsoft products are like that.

Comment: Did you hibernate your system ... If yes then in many cases i have seen issue with the network binding , a reboot fixes the issue

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee I didn't but just tried restarting, the problem persists

Comment: When you restarted, did you bind you ports to host ip?

Comment: @Not_Dave No I didn't do anything. My container's status magically went down and when I started it with `docker container start <id>`, everything worked again